# how to enable CORS in standalone ruby file

Tags: ruby, http, cors

`

## http_server.rb

```
require 'socket'
require 'json'
server = TCPServer.new 5678

while session = server.accept
request = session.gets
puts request

session.print "HTTP/1.1 200\r\n" # 1
session.print "Content-Type: text/html\r\n" # 2
session.print "\r\n" # 3
output = {
"error" => false,
"total_marks" => "0"
}

session.puts(output.to_json);

session.close
end
```

`
So this standalone ruby http server file works perfectly locally , I would prefer not to have to use rails because I also need to make it a docker container . is there any way to enable cors solely inside this file for this simple server ?

I'm new to docker and ruby so the less complex the better.

Answer (score -1):

CORS is just an `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header (see the documentation here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) so it's easy to add it to your example.

```
session.print "Access-Control-Allow-Origin: something.com\r\n"
```

Comment: Thank you!! , glad there was a simple way